# Run multiple python version on SQL Server (2017)

Tags: python, sql-server, microsoft-machine-learning-server

Is it possible to run multiple Python versions on `SQL Sever 2017`?

It is possible to do on Windows (2 Python folders, 2 shortcuts, 2 environment paths). But how to launch another Python version if I run Python via `sp_execute_external_script` in SQL Management Studio 18?

In `SQL server\Launchpad\properties\Binary` path there is the parameter `-launcher Pythonlauncher`. Probably, by changing this, it is possible to run another Python version.

Other guess: to create multiple Python folders `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES`. But how to switch them?

Other guess: in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\pythonlauncher.config` - in `PYTHONHOME` and `ENV_ExaMpiCommDllPath` parameters substitute the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\` with the folder with new Python version.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

1. Copy in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\

folder as many Python versions as you want (Python version = folder with Python like PYTHON_SERVICES)

2. Stop Launchpad
3. Change in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\pythonlauncher.config

file: in PYTHONHOME and ENV_ExaMpiCommDllPath parameters substitute the folder

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\

with the folder with new Python version.

4. Start Launchpad